# I want to restore my Galaxy Tab 10.1 to Factory settings?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, factory-reset, samsung-galaxy-tab-10

As my question suggests I want to restore my Galaxy Tab 10.1 to factory settings.  I read [this previous question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/20754/how-do-i-factory-reset-a-galaxy-tab) and it tells me how to do it and I will follow these instructions, however....

I am giving the device to a non-family member and need absolute assurance that all apps I purchased (free or otherwise) and that all log-files and personal information will be removed.  Will the reset instructions in the previous question achieve this and is there any thing else I need to do from a privacy perspective other than the described factory reset?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provided you haven't rooted the device, a factory reset will reset the phone to the state it was in. Note that sometimes, some extra content that was added by the manufacturer (like some bundled music/images) later may be wiped.

Obviously, if you're bundling along the same SD card that you were using earlier, format it and also run it through shredder programs.

Ideally, don't part with the same SD card - either give the next owner a new card or avoid it altogether.

Comment: What shredder program is advisable for an SD Card ?